# Bootstrap 'home button always pressed'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nav, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I've got this strange problem with bootstrap, and I've searched around stack overflow as well as other sources to no avail. Basically, my 'Home' button on my nav is always pressed in, even when I am on the 'About' page or any other for that matter.

Here is an image of my nav so you can see what I am talking about.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/78G3P.png

I hope we solve this one guys!

Comment: Could you include a fiddler, or some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely have the `active` class set on the home element in a template. It should be set for the currently active page, not hardcoded to home. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar

Comment: Ah that makes sense, let me try that